# How to add object to an array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component:

```
class KandidaatList extends Component
{
  public $message = '';
  public $kandidaten = [];
  
  public function mount()
    {
        $this->message = 'asd';
        $this->kandidaten = ['asd', 'qwe'];
    }
}
```

And in my view I output the value:

```
@foreach ($kandidaten as $kandidaat)
  <p>{{$kandidaat}}</p>
@endforeach
```

This works, but instead of just a string I want to put a object in the array:

```
$this->kandidaten = [{"value" = "asd"}, {"value" = "qwe"}];
```

And output it as:

```
@foreach ($kandidaten as $kandidaat)
  <p>{{$kandidaat.value}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Running this returns:

> syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve your goal is adding a nested array:

```
$this->kandidaten = [
  [
    "voornaam" => "Peter",
    "achternaam" => "Smith",
  ], 
  [
    "voornaam" => "John",
    "achternaam" => "Doe",
  ], 
];
```

Then you can iterate:

```
@foreach ($kandidaten as $kandidaat)
  <p>Voornaam: {{ $kandidaat['voornaam'] }}</p>
  <p>Achternaam: {{ $kandidaat['achternaam'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->kandidaten = [{"value":"asd", "value":"qwe"}];
```

I hope this code will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 $this->kandidaten = '[{"value" : "asd"}, {"value" : "qwe"}]';
```

and in blade file,

```
  foreach (json_decode($kandidaten) as $kandidaat) {
       dump($kandidaat->value);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your syntax. In livewire you need to define values as PHP arrays & objects not JavaScript objects. Try the below snippets.

```
$this->kandidaten = [
  (object) array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'),
  (object) array('key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'),
];
```

and in you blade template render the same using the below snippet.

```
@foreach($kandidaten as $kandidaat)
  <p>{{$kandidaat->key}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Replace "key" with your object key.

Hope this helps your out.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to work with string, so you define a true object.

example:

```
$ob = new stdClass();
$ob->value = 'Jhon';

$kandidaten[] = $ob;

@foreach ($kandidaten as $kandidaat)
   <p>{{$kandidaat.value}}</p>
@endforeach
```

You can also use the functions:
json_encode and / or json_decode to start objects as a string and convert to array, or the other way around.